# How slicing numpy load file is loaded into memory

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

If I want to load a portion of a file using `numpy.load`, I use slicing as:

`np.load('myfile.npy')[start:end]`.

Does this guarantee that this portion from the file, i.e., `[start:end]`, is only loaded into to memory or does it load the entire file first then slice it?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That loads the whole thing. If you don't want to load the whole thing, you could mmap the file and only copy the part you want:

```
part = numpy.load('myfile.npy', mmap_mode='r')[start:end].copy()
```

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you so much