# How to use numpy.save in append mode

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, numpy

I use `numpy.save` and `numpy.load` to R/W **large** datasets in my project. I realized that that `numpy.save` does not apply append mode. For instance (Python 3):

```
import numpy as np

n = 5
dim = 5
for _ in range(3):
    Matrix = np.random.choice(np.arange(10, 40, dim), size=(n, dim))
    np.save('myfile', Matrix)

M1 = np.load('myfile.npy', mmap_mode='r')[1:7].copy()
print(M1)
```

Loading specific portion of data using slicing `[1:7]` is not correct because the `np.save` does not append. I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42496363/9559720) but it looks strange ( `file(filename, 'a')` what is file `file`??). Is there a clever workaround to achieve that without using additional lists?

Comment: That `a` and `file` means use open a file in append mode

Comment: *"what is `file`?"* It is a [Python 2 builtin function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#file).  It was removed in Python 3.

Comment: @Zhiya Yes, but it will complain like this `write() argument must be str, not bytes` which is because of `Matrix`

Comment: @Medo Can we see your code and error ?

Comment: `np.load('myfile.npy', mmap_mode='r')[1:7]` wouldn't have worked anyway. The `npy` file format doesn't work that way.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Thank you. I just realized that!! I started learning Python from Python 3

Comment: @user2357112 but it is working in non-append mode. I use this load to save memory (not loading the entire file). It was suggested by this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49518962/how-slicing-numpy-load-file-is-loaded-into-memory/49519121#49519121

Comment: @Medo: I know. I wrote that answer. What I mean is that even if you got `np.save` to append the data, the resulting file contents wouldn't be a valid npy file representing a combined array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `npy` file format doesn't work that way. An `npy` file encodes a *single* array, with a header specifying shape, dtype, and other metadata. You can see the [`npy` file format spec](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/neps/npy-format.html) in the NumPy docs.

Support for appending data was not a design goal of the `npy` format. Even if you managed to get `numpy.save` to append to an existing file instead of overwriting the contents, the result wouldn't be a valid `npy` file. Producing a valid `npy` file with additional data would require rewriting the header, and since this could require resizing the header, it could shift the data and require the whole file to be rewritten.

NumPy comes with no tools to append data to existing `npy` files, beyond reading the data into memory, building a new array, and writing the new array to a file. If you want to save more data, consider writing a new file, or pick a different file format.

Comment: Make sense! Thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

In Python3 repeated `save` and `load` to the same open file works:

```
In [113]: f = open('test.npy', 'wb')
In [114]: np.save(f, np.arange(10))
In [115]: np.save(f, np.zeros(10))
In [116]: np.save(f, np.ones(10))
In [117]: f.close()
In [118]: f = open('test.npy', 'rb')
In [119]: for _ in range(3):
     ...:     print(np.load(f))
     ...:     
[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
[1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
In [120]: np.load(f)
OSError: Failed to interpret file <_io.BufferedReader name='test.npy'> as a pickle
```

Each `save` writes a self contained block of data to the file.  That consists of a header block, and an image of the databuffer.  The header block has information about the length of the databuffer.

Each load reads the defined header block, and the known number of data bytes.

As far as I know this is not documented, but has been demonstrated in previous SO questions.  It is also evident from the `save` and `load` code.

Note these are separate arrays, both on saving and loading.  But we could concatenate the loads into one file if the dimensions are compatible.

```
In [122]: f = open('test.npy', 'rb')
In [123]: np.stack([np.load(f) for _ in range(3)])
Out[123]: 
array([[0., 1., 2., 3., 4., 5., 6., 7., 8., 9.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.]])
In [124]: f.close()
```

[Append multiple numpy files to one big numpy file in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42160582/append-multiple-numpy-files-to-one-big-numpy-file-in-python)

[loading arrays saved using numpy.save in append mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35747614/loading-arrays-saved-using-numpy-save-in-append-mode)

Comment: It's worth noting that this is incompatible with `mmap_mode`, which the questioner is using. Aside from that, I'd like to say that calling such a file `anything.npy` is misleading when the contents are really an ad-hoc format based on NPY, and that I'd recommend a different form of data storage. For example, the `npz` format, which is just a zip file with `npy` files inside, which you can manipulate and add data to with the `zipfile` standard library module.

Answer (score 1):

The `file` function was deprecated in Python 3. Though I won't guarantee that it works, the Python 3 code equivalent to the code in the link in your question would be

```
with open('myfile.npy', 'ab') as f_handle:
    np.save(f_handle, Matrix)
```

This should then append `Matrix` to `'myfile.npy'`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried your suggestion but because `Matrix` is numpy list, I get this error `TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes`